# How to solve problem with a for loop in python?

Tags: python

I send my gardener to pick some apples from a tree. I give him 3 attempts to catch an red apple and 2 attempts to catch the green one. He should repeat that process 4 times.

PROBLEM: Why is he sometimes trying to catch an green apple for 3 times?

```
import random

def garden():
        green_apple = 0
        red_apple = 0
        tree = 50
        for _ in range(4):
            for _ in range(3):
                x = random.randint(1,10)
                if x >= 7:
                    tree -= 1
                    print('You catch an red apple! There are ' + str(tree) + ' apples left on the tree')
                    red_apple += 1
                if x <= 6:
                    print('No red apples this time')
            for _ in range (2): 
                y = random.randint(1,10)   
                if y >= 5:
                    tree -= 1
                    print('You catch an green apple! There are ' + str(tree) + ' apples left on the tree')
                    green_apple += 1
                if y <=5:
                    print('No green apples this time')    

        print('################################################')  
        return (red_apple, green_apple)

green_bag, red_bag = [], []

for _ in range(3):
    green_apple, red_apple = garden()
    green_bag.append(green_apple)
    red_bag.append(red_apple)

print(red_bag)
print(green_bag)
```

SAMPLE:

```
You catch an green apple! There are 39 apples left on the tree
You catch an green apple! There are 38 apples left on the tree
No green apples this time
################################################
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if y >= 5:
    tree -= 1
    print('You catch an green apple! There are ' + str(tree) + ' apples left on the tree')
    green_apple += 1
if y <=5:
    print('No green apples this time')
```

You have `if y >= 5` and `if y <=5`. If `y` equals to `5`, *both* the conditions meets, and so, both blocks will be initiated. You can fix it by changing `>=` to `>` or `<=` to `<`. Or, change the second `if` to an `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a typo. In your second for loop you have both conditions triggered when y==5. You catch a green apple and also not catch a green apple at the same y value.

You can do an if-else block there, or do an elif statement so both don't get executed on same input.

```
for _ in range (2): 
            y = random.randint(1,10)   
            if y >= 5:
                tree -= 1
                print('You catch an green apple! There are ' + str(tree) + ' apples left on the tree')
                green_apple += 1
            else:
                print('No green apples this time')
```

Comment: It's not called a typo.

Comment: I assumed a simple mistake of adding an extra '='. But I could see how it could be a logic error too.